# Laravel login expired when the browser was closed

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

I am developing a web application using laravel.

In session config file the values are `lifetime=2880` and `expire_on_close=false`,
but when the browser is closed, the login is expired but the session doesn't expire.

It still exists. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: As we have added the answer. You should check and reply Or tell us if you face any issue or at least we know where we are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case, you will need to check the value of "expire_on_close" in config/session.php file.

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

The value is self-explanatory.